# Execute *.exe in current package and run it

Tags: java

I can't seem to figure this out? I wan;t to execute dec.exe with param

Here my file structure:

[image: structure]

Here my code that i'm using on mouse click.

```
Process process = null; 

try { 

    process = new ProcessBuilder("dec.exe",idir,odir).start(); 

} catch (IOException e2) { e2.printStackTrace(); } 

InputStream is = process.getInputStream(); 
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new  BufferedReader(isr); 

String line; 
String total = "";

try { 
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
        total += line;
        txtrAsdasda.setText(total);
    }
} 

} catch (IOException e1) { e1.printStackTrace(); }
```

---

**I get the following error:**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at pw.ConverterUIApp$3.actionPerformed(ConverterUIApp.java:128)

...
```

and

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "dec.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: And what is the `crysis.pak`??

Comment: @Andremoniy I don't think it's crysis.pak. It's just his project name is crysis3pak

Comment: Everything is provided above. Why the down votes? crysis3pak is just a project name, ignore.

Comment: @CezarisLT because nobody cares about structure of your project! It doesn't belong to here. Furthermore, you did not provided what these variables are: `idir`, `odir`? It seems, that one of them is `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it my self, it's all about selecting the correct file with corrent linking:

```
process = new ProcessBuilder("dec.exe",idir,odir).start();
```

I put the dec.exe beside the .jar from export.

Comment: Note that your solution had nothing to do with your original problem.  Your original problem was that you were using a null where one was not allowed.

Comment: Once packaged as a Jar, this will no longer work. You should never include the `src` element in any resource path, it will not exist once you application is packaged.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Soo how do i fix this? exclude src?

Comment: You have two choices.  Either don't included in the application package and have it installed along side your Jar or place the executable in the resources folder and extract them from the resulting Jar at runtime.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Really? that the easiest way of doing this? Please tell me there an easier alternative?

Comment: What could be easier?  Coping all the files required to run your application to a single directory?

Answer (score 0):

Once your application is packaged, you will not be able launch the executable while it is embedded within your application Jar.

Embedded resources of this type are just Zip entries in a zip file, the OS will not be able to recognize or find this resource to execute it.

You have two choices.

1. Don't package these resources within the application Jar, but instead, have the installed along side the application.  This will allow you to simply call `ProcessBuilder("dec.exe")` (assuming your application was started in the same directory)
2. Place the executables (and other resources) into the `resources` folder and extract them at runtime.  It is imperative that all the associated files required by the executable are extracted!

Answer (score -1):

The likely cause is that either `idir` or `odir` is null.

Comment: It just provides another error. Something to do with linking to the file?

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "dec.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: @Andremoniy I still get the same error bellow it, its just an extra error trown without the param. I don't need your offensive nature.

Comment: @CezarisLT If you'd taken the time to Google, you would have found that `CreateProcess error=2` is actually the OS's way of saying it can't find the program you are trying to execute.